# Aurelia ValueConverter fromView confusion with multi-select

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to use and understand the Aurelia ValueConverter in the context of a multi-select form. What I thought would be straight forward, has turned out to be a challenge for me.

I have a form to create a new deal which has multiple categories assigned to it via a multi-select input field. I've bound the output from the form into new_deal.categorizations (in the database deals have categories through categorizations).

Right now on create, through a 'brute force' method, I'm converting each category ID into a {category_id: id} object before posting to the API.

Example just logging the POST output:

```
  create(){
      var categorizations = this.new_deal.categorizations;
      this.new_deal.categorizations = categorizations.map(function (e) {
          return {category_id: e}
      });
      logger.debug ('POST: ', JSON.stringify(this.new_deal));
  }
```

Example output:

```
POST:  {"name":"new deal","categorizations":[{"category_id":"1"},{"category_id":"2"}]}
```

But I think this would better be accomplished through a ValueConverter.

Plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YQ06IlR0nJtirZmkpZk5?p=info) with the full code but it's basically:

app.js:

```
export class App {
  constructor(){
    this.categories = [{id: 1, name: 'test1'}, {id: 2, name: 'test2'}];
    this.new_deal = {
        name:       'new deal',
        categorizations: null,
    };
  }

  create(){
      var categorizations = this.new_deal.categorizations;
      this.new_deal.categorizations = categorizations.map(function (e) {return {category_id: e}});
      logger.debug ('POST: ', JSON.stringify(this.new_deal));
  }

  create2(){
      logger.debug ('POST: ', JSON.stringify(this.new_deal));
  }

}

export class CategoryToIDValueConverter {
    fromView(id) {
        return id ? id: null;
    }
}
```

And app.html:

```
<template>
  <h1>Testing ValueConverter</h1>
   <h3 >New Brute Force Deal</h3>
     <form role="form">
       <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Ex. Buy One Get One Free" value.bind="new_deal.name">
       <label>Categories</label>
          <select value.bind="new_deal.categorizations" multiple size="2">
              <option repeat.for="category of categories" value.bind="category.id">${category.name}</option>
          </select>
       </form>
       <button type="submit" click.delegate="create()">Save</button>

  <h3>New ValueConverter Deal</h3>
    <form role="form">
      <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Ex. Buy One Get One Free" value.bind="new_deal.name">
      <label>Categories</label>
          <select class="form-control" value.bind="new_deal.categorizations | categoryToID" multiple size="2">
            <option repeat.for="category of categories" value.bind="category.id">${category.name}</option>
          </select>
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" click.delegate="create2()">Save</button>
</template>
```

With this I get an output of

```
POST:  {"name":"new deal","categorizations":["1","2"]}
```

In fromView in app.js, I would think I could change:

```
return id ? id: null;
```

To return an object instead of an individual value:

```
return id ? {category_id: id} : null
```

But that results in this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Only null or Array instances can be bound to a multi-select.
```

Upon further inspection, it looks like id is coming into fromView as an array...

So I modified fromView to this:

```
    fromView(id) {
        if(id){
          var categorizations = [];
          id.forEach(function(cat_id){
            categorizations.push({category_id: cat_id})
          });
          logger.debug(categorizations);
          logger.debug(Object.prototype.toString.call(categorizations));
          return categorizations;
        } else { return null; }
    }
}
```

Trying to expect an array, and then build an array of categorization objects to return, but as you can see in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CsJISCeYSNt7NCqvJNtL?p=preview), it loses the select as you click (though the debug logs show the objects being created).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of category objects, each having a `name` (string) and `id` (number).  These will be used to populate a select element that allows multiple selection:

```js
export class App {
  categories = [
    { id: 1, name: 'test1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'test2'}
  ];
}
```

```html
<select multiple size="2">
  <option repeat.for="category of categories">${category.name}</option>
</select>
```

The deal object is comprised of a `name` (string) and `categorizations`. Categorization objects look like this: `{ category_id: 1 }`

```js
export class App {
  categories = [
    { id: 1, name: 'test1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'test2'}];

  deal = {
    name: 'new deal',
    categorizations: [],
  }
}
```

We want to bind the select element's value to the deal object's categorizations which is an array of objects.  This means each of the select element's options need to have a object "value".  An HTMLOptionElement's value attribute only accepts strings.  Anything we assign to it will be coerced to a string.  We can store the categorization object in a special `model` attribute which can handle any type.  More info on this can be found in the [aurelia docs](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#select-elements).

```html
<select multiple size="2">
  <option repeat.for="category of categories" model.bind="{ category_id: category.id }">${category.name}</option>
</select>
```

Finally we need to bind the select element's value to the deal object's categorizations:

```html
<select value.bind="deal.categorizations" multiple size="2">
  <option repeat.for="category of categories" model.bind="{ category_id: category.id }">${category.name}</option>
</select>
```

All together, the view and view-model look like this:

```js
export class App {
  categories = [
    { id: 1, name: 'test1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'test2'}];

  deal = {
    name: 'new deal',
    categorizations: [],
  }

  createDeal() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.deal, null, 2));
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <form submit.delegate="createDeal()">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ex. Buy One Get One Free" value.bind="deal.name">

    <label>Categories</label>
    <select value.bind="deal.categorizations" multiple size="2">
      <option repeat.for="category of categories" model.bind="{ category_id: category.id }">${category.name}</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Here's a working plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/KO3iFBostdThrHUA0QHY?p=preview

Comment: I've got it working up to the point you described (see the Plunkers I linked), but what I'm trying for is not for new_deal.categorizations to be an array of integers, but an array of objects:

This:
`{"name":"new deal","categorizations":[{"category_id":"1"},{"category_id":"2"}]}`

Instead of this (which it currently is):
`{"name":"new deal","categorizations":["1","2"]}`

Comment: And I just figured it out with some help in the Aurelia Gitter channel. I'll post the answer here in a few in case this is puzzling for anyone else.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I tweaked my answer to reflect the output you were looking for in case you wanted an approach without requiring a value converter.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with some help from [whayes](https://github.com/wshayes) on the Aurelia Gitter channel. So I was on the right track with expecting an array in the fromView method but I also needed a toView method in the ValueConverter.

```js
export class CategoryToIDValueConverter {
    toView(cats){
      if (cats){
        var ids = [];
        cats.forEach(function(categorization){
          ids.push(categorization.category_id);
        });
        return ids;
      } else { return null; }
    }
    fromView(id) {
        if(id){
          var categorizations = [];
          id.forEach(function(cat_id){
            categorizations.push({category_id: cat_id})
          });
          return categorizations;
        } else { return null; }
    }
}
```

I had tried that too, but I initially assumed I needed to add the converter to the select line of the form and the option line, like so:

```html
<select class="form-control" value.bind="new_deal.categorizations | categoryToID" multiple size="2">
            <option repeat.for="category of categories" value.bind="category.id">${category.name}</option>
          </select>
```

But that's actually incorrect. I only needed to apply the categoryToID ValueConverter to the select line and it all worked as expected.

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3oq0WXqUDMz9GwUlnwpa?p=preview) showing how the brute force method doesn't change the model until you click save, and the ValueConverter changes it any time you change the selection.

Final app.js

```js
import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';
let logger = LogManager.getLogger('testItems');

export class App {
  constructor(){
    this.categories = [{id: 1, name: 'test1'}, {id: 2, name: 'test2'}];
    this.new_deal = {
        name:       'new deal',
        categorizations: [],
    };
    setInterval(() => this.debug = JSON.stringify(this.new_deal, null, 2), 100);
  }

  create(){
      var categorizations = this.new_deal.categorizations;
      this.new_deal.categorizations = categorizations.map(function (e) {return {category_id: e}});
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.new_deal, null, 2));
  }

  create2(){
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.new_deal, null, 2));
  }
}

export class CategoryToIDValueConverter {
    toView(cats){
      if (cats){
        var ids = [];
        cats.forEach(function(categorization){
          ids.push(categorization.category_id);
        });
        return ids;
      } else { return null; }
    }
    fromView(id) {
        if(id){
          var categorizations = [];
          id.forEach(function(cat_id){
            categorizations.push({category_id: cat_id})
          });
          return categorizations;
        } else { return null; }
    }
}
```

Final app.html

```html
<template>
  <h1>Testing ValueConverter</h1>
   <h3 >New Brute Force Deal</h3>
     <form role="form">
       <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Ex. Buy One Get One Free" value.bind="new_deal.name">
       <label>Categories</label>
          <select value.bind="new_deal.categorizations" multiple size="2">
              <option repeat.for="category of categories" value.bind="category.id">${category.name}</option>
          </select>
       </form>
       <button type="submit" click.delegate="create()">Save</button>

  <h3>New ValueConverter Deal</h3>
    <form role="form">
      <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Ex. Buy One Get One Free" value.bind="new_deal.name">
      <label>Categories</label>
          <select class="form-control" value.bind="new_deal.categorizations | categoryToID" multiple size="2">
            <option repeat.for="category of categories" value.bind="category.id">${category.name}</option>
          </select>
    </form>
    <button type="submit" click.delegate="create2()">Save</button>

  <!-- debug -->
  <pre><code>${debug}</code></pre>
</template>
```