# Only null or Array instances can be bound to a multi-select

Tags: aurelia

I'm building a multi-step form in Aurelia where each page shows one question.

I use the same view for every question, with `if` statements determining what type of form field to show.

When I try to bind my question data to a multiple select element however, Aurelia throws errors and says "Only null or Array instances can be bound to a multi-select.".

What's really strange is that if the *first* question is a multiple select I don't get the error until I come to a non-multiselect question and then go back to the multiselect question.

I can solve this entire problem by setting `activationStrategy: 'replace'` for this route, but I really don't want that.

The important code follows:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class Form {
  constructor (router) {
    this.router = router;
    this.active = 0;
    this.field = null;
    this.fields = [
      {
        type: 'text',
        value: null
      },
      {
        type: 'select',
        value: [],
        options: [
          'foo',
          'bar'
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'select',
        value: [],
        options: [
          'foo',
          'bar'
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'text',
        value: null
      },
    ];
  }

  activate (routeParams) {
    this.active = routeParams.fieldIndex || 0;
    this.active = parseInt(this.active);
    this.field = this.fields[this.active];
  }

  prev () {
    if (typeof this.fields[this.active - 1] !== 'undefined') {
            this.router.navigateToRoute('form', {
                fieldIndex: this.active - 1
            });

            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
  }

  next () {
    if (typeof this.fields[this.active + 1] !== 'undefined') {
            this.router.navigateToRoute('form', {
                fieldIndex: this.active + 1
            });

            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
  }
}
```

And the template:

```
<template>
  <div class="select" if.bind="field.type == 'select'">
    <select value.bind="field.value" multiple="multiple">
        <option repeat.for="option of field.options" value.bind="option">${option}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="text" if.bind="field.type == 'text'">
    <input type="text" value.bind="field.value">
  </div>

  <a click.delegate="prev()">Previous</a> | <a click.delegate="next()">Next</a>
</template>
```

But you'll probably want to check out the GistRun: https://gist.run/?id=4d7a0842929dc4086153e29e03afbb7a to get a better understanding.

Try setting the first question to a multiselect and you'll notice the error disappears (until you go back to it). You can also try `activationStrategy` in app.js like mentioned above.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Also note that in my real app I'm actually using `compose` instead of `if`s but have tried with both and both produce the same error. It almost seems as if the select values are bound before the if is evaluated, causing the error to show up because the `text` field type lacks the `options` array.

Comment: I think the issue is down to the use of a multiselect, and `value.bind` on the `<select>` AND on the `<option>` elements. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32300539/297243) should help you out I think. It's because your `value.bind` on the select input is an array in `fields[n]['value'][]` but its trying to bind to a string in `fields[n]['options']`.

Comment: @thebluefox thanks for your help. However, I don't follow :/ Removing the `value.bind` from the option doesn't help. Note that the code works fine under certain circumstances so I doubt there's anything wrong with the actual data binding.

Comment: By that logic though none of the code is wrong seeing as it all works under some circumstances ;) I see the point about that answer though. I just tested with binding the `<select>` to an empty test array (that wasn't inside an object) and that worked. I added `console.log(this.field.value)` into the `activate()` function. Eventually - the array in question starts containing `[__array_observer__: ModifyArrayObserver]` - at which point it falls over. Looks like it isn't a plain enough Array anymore.

Comment: Fair enough, but my suspicion is that this is actually a bug in Aurelia - not my code. Could you perhaps update the Gist with your suggestion and get rid of the error? I failed.

Comment: The question you linked to isn't related either. I'm not even using objects but an array of strings. Again, I doubt there's anything wrong with the actual binding of the data. If it was it would _never_ work. Now it works except in rare cases where you navigate to and from select<->input field types.

Comment: Maybe one of the Aurelia team members will correct me, but I don't believe you can change the bound value for a select or input element on the fly. I'd use routing to move between your steps with urls that end in /1, /2, or the like. Then you can easily move through the array of steps using the number in the url. Also, this would probably be a good situation in which to use a child router.

Comment: I am using routing though, but without `activationStrategy: replace` I still get errors. If you can't change the bound value on the fly, how come it works when navigating from one select to another select? Only when I go from text to select do I get the error (because the text field lacks the options array and doesn't have an empty array as its value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out swapping the order of the HTML, and putting the `select` *after* the `input` solves this issue.

Jeremy Danyow explains it like this:

> When Form.field changes, the bindings subscribing to that property's changes evaluate sequentially. Which means there's a period of time when the select AND the input are both on the page. The html input element coaleses null values to empty string which in turn causes field.value to be empty string, which makes the multi-select throw.

Very tricky to track down imo but I'm glad the Aurelia devs are so helpful over on Github.

Working Gist: https://gist.run/?id=3f88b2c31f27f0f435afe14e89b13d56

Answer (score 1):

A little late but I wanted to give a suggestion -- for SELECT multi-selects, you should decouple the bound variable from the multi-selector to prevent those errors.

For example, if you in your custom elements that bind to 'selected', they should bind to:

`<select multiple value.two-way="selectedDecoupled">`

Then when the actual variable 'selected' changes, it only changes in the custom element if the bound value is an array:

```
selectedChanged( newV, oldV ){
    if( typeof newV =='object' )
        this.selectedDecoupled = newV;
    else
        this.selectedDecoupled = [];
    $(this.SELECT).val(this.selectedDecoupled ).trigger('change');
}
```

Example of it in use with a custom select2 element:

https://github.com/codefreeze8/aurelia-select2